# Get files in directory by modifying time

Tags: c++, sorting, time

I would like to write a C++ function that fills a vector with the filename of all of the files in a directory. Furthermore, I would like this vector to be ordered by the last modified time of the files.

I can use boost:: filesystem to read in all of the files in the directory and pass it to a vector, but these get loaded to the vector by filename and then I have stat the file and perform a sort which is not very efficient.

Does anybody know of a quick way to do this? For instance, ls -lhctr can do it almost instantly so C++ should be able to do this very quickly for a large directory as well.

I would also like this to have sub-millisecond resolution if possible.

Comment: You mentioned `boost::filesystem` -- what's wrong with calling [`last_write_time`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#last_write_time)?

Comment: Even if you would have to perform a sort after, I am doubtful that it would take very long to do so in all but the most enormous of directories. My first recommendation is that you try it with Boost and make sure that it's not fast enough for your purposes, before you try something more complex. You may find that this solution is good enough.

Comment: The boost version is not fast enough, for a directory with 700 files, it takes about 2 seconds...

Comment: @user788171 it shows profiling?

Comment: I didn't do any profiling, I got those numbers by doing a simple test with a time before and after the function call.

Comment: @user788171 Are you sure it is the sorting part that is taking time and not the filesystem calls to iterate over the directory? I find it hard to believe that sorting a vector containing 700 elements takes 2 seconds. Also, did you compile with optimizations turned on?

Comment: @user788171 premature optimization is evil.

Comment: @user788171 : Sanity check -- did you get those numbers by measuring a release build or a debug build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `map/multimap<std::time_t/dt::ptime, std::string/fs::path>`?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how this works?  Also, what is the time resolution of this?  If there are two files created within 1 milliseconds of each other, can this distinguish them?

Comment: @user788171 usage example. mb multimap will be better.
http://liveworkspace.org/code/e1728a60450e2b06d6c11fa0445a0e56

Answer (score 2):

You could use Boost.Filesystem to iterate over the directory, and call [`last_write_time()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#last_write_time) on each file.

Then store the file name in an [std::multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) using the result of the `last_write_time` call as the key. That way the sorting is done automatically upon insertion into the container.

Comment: I am not very familiar with std::multimap, can you give a short code example of this and some more details about why this is more efficient so I can try to understand? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user788171 The link I posted has a good description of `multimap`. Basically, it is the same as an `std::map` except that each key can have more than one value associated with it. So, if the directory contains more than one file having the same modified time they can all be stored in the container. The benefit of using the `multimap` is that it is a sorted container, when you insert a value it is sorted according to the key value (in your case modified time) and comparison predicate prior to insertion.

Comment: what is the time resolution of the time?  can it distinguish two files created 1 microsecond apart? how about 1 millisecond?

Comment: @user788171 The resolution is as good as that of the type of `std::time_t` and the filesystem implementation of your platform.

Answer (score 0):

I know that within Qt's framework there is a QFileInfo class that will provide that info. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfileinfo.html

I'm not as familiar with boost, but I think this should work similarly: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/filesystem/doc/operations.htm#last_write_time

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to start up the great C++ system() fight, but you mentioned "ls -lhctr" returns your answer almost immediately, so why not use the system() function?  Try:

`system("ls -lhctr > out.txt");`

And then use the fstream header to getline() that data?

Using system(), of course, guarantees that this solution won't be portable to other OSes, but you may not care about doing that anyway.